# TexShop/El Capitan update: some figures not showing

Tags: floats, pdftex

So I updated to El Capitan and I reconfigured the Latex paths from /usr/bin/ to the /Library/Tex/ etc. and my document compiles fine, with no error messages in the screen output, EXCEPT certain .eps figures just simply do not show up in the document.

I've tried:

- changing the order of the Figures and it seems the first two figures (whichever I specify) are the only ones that show (so it's not an issue with the figures/.eps files themselves)
- compiling a .tex file, which worked and showed all figures before the El Capitan update and sure enough, only about 2-3 figures showed compared to the 20 or so that are meant to show.
- changing the sizes of the figures, whether they go across both columns or just one and that has no effect.
- pdflatex instead of latex, dvipdfm and the output is the same.

Anyone ideas what's going on?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.
Specially considering a specific class. Also, just in case, have you tried deleting the .aux file? Sometimes when I can't think of what to try this the last on my list, never hurt trying.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try updating all your packages through TexLive? I had a few strange problems with El Capitan, but since I updated TexLive everything is working properly.

Comment: I guess this is more a comment than an answer...?